# Solving Error:(102, 82) error: cannot find symbol class ListCallbackSingleChoice error

Tags: android

I'm trying to make things work so I can finally build the apk for an app I develope, but I'm facing with this two errors:

```
Error:(102, 82) error: cannot find symbol class ListCallbackSingleChoice
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The first errors, is shown at this line: `.itemsCallbackSingleChoice(-1, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice() {`

I'm searching for few hours now, and I can't do anything. What should I do in order to make it work? Thanks in advance.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.panaceasoft.citiesdirectory"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    compile ('com.github.afollestad:material-dialogs:53103863a6') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
}
```

Comment: By the way, your `play-services` is out of date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build.gradle file, try replacing 
`compile ('com.github.afollestad:material-dialogs:53103863a6') { transitive = true }`

to

```
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.6.1'
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.6.1'
```

Then rebuild your project.

Comment: Now it says: `Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html` and `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

Comment: try removing the second line (commons) then, you probably won't need it. Otherwise you'll have to use proguard/multidex

Comment: Finally, it builds the apk, but crashes when it starts. Thanks a lot sir !

Comment: if the crash is due to missing classes in com.afollestad.material, you'll need to look up [multidexing](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: Actually, it crashes because of this: `Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView`

Comment: okay, it is probably a separate issue then, if you have trouble solving it feel free to post another separate question!